# Disable a column

Tags: javascript, netsuite

can someone please help me figure out how can I disable the column in netsuite.

The screenshot will well explain the problem.

[image]

This is my client script loaded before init function.

```
function disableInvoiceColumn(type)
{
    nlapiDisableLineItemField(type, 'quantity', true);
    .........
    ......
}
```

Comment: I think this belongs in SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your function in the Line Init client event.

Comment: I already did that. I am sure about my i'ds so there's no reason that this will not work. Just made it to other columns.

Comment: I re-read your question and it looks like you wanted to disable the Inventory Detail column.  I dont think that is possible since Inventory Detail is not actually a column field on the transaction but a sub-record.  It is only  displayed that way in the UI.